# Javascript async function: cutting it short at the top with return

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, return

I have an asynchronous function that checks for a few things and runs itself over and over using setTimeout and a queue.pop().
After some logic is true, I don't need the function to keep going and keep calling itself, even if some element remain in the queue. So I have a statement at some point like the following:

```
if (isWhatIneed(currentItem)) {
   completed = true;
   return;
}
```

I've got what I was looking for. The problem is that the queue has been fed more items since then and it keeps being executed asynchronously. So to remedy to this I've added at the very top of that function:

```
if (completed) {
  console.log("already completed");
  return;
}
```

This prevents each execution in the stack of calls from doing anything further (especially not to pop more items from the queue and keep running).

My question is, I've read using multiple return statements esp. at the top of a function is poor practice. But in this case do you see another way this could be done? I could wrap the whole body of my function with if (!completed) { //... } but this strikes me as ugly also because it indents the whole body, the early return does not.

Thanks,

Comment: Where did you read that it's poor practice to have a return statement at the top of a function? It's far, _far_ better than wrapping the whole body.

Comment: I think I read that from MDN maybe, in which it says there should only be one return... Not sure anymore. Thanks for the comment! :-)

Comment: I second James' opionion. I have also heard of this, that it's bad to have multiple returns because it makes the code paths harder to follow, but in cases like this, I think it's preferable and clear.

Comment: I think it is actually a good practice. I use it a lot. I don't like the extra indentation level other solutions would bring.

Comment: It's not your question, but still: why don't you simply clear the queue once `completed = true`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in using multiple return statements especially in this type of cases.

For example the `return` could be a value in which case you could just verify if the function was success or other error messages.

There is no problem with the speed if you have multiple `return` statements inside a function, and the issue about following the paths of the code, well you do not use a jump, so there is no problem in this method. The function will return where you called it not on other line. (please implement a recursive backtracking algorithm without using multiple returns, it's impracticable );

So therefore i suggest using multiple return statements with no worries.